# UIImage or UIImageView with paging and zoom on click

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIView in which I get certain information about a user, wthin a bunch of textfields and a bunch of photos of him, if available.

No Im a bit limited here, so I must have a UIImage or UIImageView on my View (only the first half of my view, to display this images.

Up to now I have a array of this images in the background and as soon as the user swipe over the UIImageView, the image shows the next.
But it's ugly, becuase there is no real paging (you know, see the second image in pieces while you swipe, at the moment its only a UIMageView.Image = xxx and its ugly) and no zooming (zoom on click).

Any idea to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use an `UIScrollView` and place all of the images in it (as `UIImageViews`).

Comment: link http://kwigbo.com/post/758575763/uiscrollview-image-gallery-tutorial seems to be broken please fix it if possible.